# How to get unshortened link from Dropbox via REST API

Tags: rest, oauth, dropbox

I have all my tokens and secrets for my app, but I don't understand how to include them in a URL (URI?) in order to get a non-shortened shareable link to a folder or file in my Dropbox  (i.e., not shortened to "http://db.tt/...." but rather the full URL)

Which tokens/keys/secrets do I need to include in my call, and how?

I want to use `curl` e.g:

`curl --stderr /dev/null https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/<root>/<path>` and so on ...

There should be something like `?oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxx&.....` after this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, I figured it out ... for anyone else who might want a quick answer:

`curl --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=1.0, oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT, oauth_consumer_key=[app_key], oauth_token=[access_token], oauth_signature=[app_secret]&[access_token_secret]' 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/[root]/[path]?short_url=false'`

`[root]` is either 'sandbox' or 'dropbox' (limited access or full access, depending on the app)